# List of running minimum values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to iterate over an enumeration of items and at each element return the smallest value iterated so far.

My code looks like:

```
var items = new List<int>{1, 2, -1, 3, -2, 1, 1, 2, -1, -3};

var min = items.First();

var drawdown = items.Select(i =>
{
    if(i < min)
    {
        min = i;
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        return min;
    }
});
```

So for the values `1, 2, -1, 3, -2, 1, 1, 2, -1, -3`

The resultant list would look like:

```
1
1
-1
-1
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-3
```

But this is not very elegant. Is there an easier to read (linq?) way of doing this? I looked into Aggregate but it seemed to be the wrong tool. Ultimately the list of items will be very long, in the many thousands. So good performance will be an issue to.

Comment: In what way is `{ 1, 2, -1, 3 ... }` a sorted list?

Comment: Yes, it is a sorted list. (let me update my question).

Comment: That code won't compile. `SortedList` doesn't do what you think it does. I suggest you come up with more than "rough draft code" so you can at least present a realistic scenario. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: ... and if you've got a list which has *really* already been sorted, then the minimum value is the first value, by definition.

Comment: I have polished my question now.

Comment: `var drawdown = items.Select(i => { min = Math.Min(min, i); return min; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method using an iterator block:

```
private IEnumerable<int> RunningMinimum(IEnumerable<int> ints)
{
    int minimum = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (int x in ints)
    {
        if (x < minimum) { minimum = x; } 
        yield return minimum;
    }
}
```

Call as follows:

```
int[] drawdown = RunningMinimum(items).ToArray();
```

Comment: I like this solution. It could be turned into an extension method. Perhaps generic as well where T could be IComparable maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var drawdown = items.Select(i =>
{
    min = Math.Min(min, i);
    return min;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] { 1, 2, -1, 3, -2, 1, 1, 2, -1, -3 };

        int min = items.First();

        Action<int> minimumSoFar = (int x) => { Console.WriteLine("{0}", Math.Min(min, x)); min = Math.Min(min, x); };

        foreach (var integer in items)
        {
            minimumSoFar.Invoke(integer);
        }
    }

}
```